# "Instance-wide" getter/setter for TypeScript class?

Tags: javascript, oop, typescript, ecmascript-6, getter-setter

So I know I can set getters/setters per property.

```
export class Person {
    private _name: string;

    set name(value) {
        this._name = value;
    }

    get name() {
        return this._name;
    }
}
```

But is there a way to have a "global instance-wide" setter that trigger whenever any property of a class instance gets modified?
Without manually adding a function call in every getter/setter calling that trigger function? Like, something built into TypeScript?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What would you need this for?

Comment: @Bergi I want to emit an event whenever the instance changes, rather than emitting it (or call an emitting function within the class) in every setter (which also requires me to add setters when I don't need them, just to be able to track the changes).

Comment: So you don't need to watch any properties, but only all the properties that the instance has. You can easily add setters to them programmatically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There isn't a built-in way in TypeScript to do this, nor a JavaScript runtime feature for it.

The closest thing would be a [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy), which can wrap an underlying object and intercept property assignments. But you'd have to make sure the class instances got wrapped before they were passed off to somewhere else.